# Storing solution to x and y

Tags: equation-solving

If I do

```
sol=Solve[{2x+2==y,3x+9==y},{x,y}]
```

then Mathematica will tell me

```
{{x -> -7, y -> -12}}
```

But I would like to store values to x and y even if I don't write the following thing explicitly.

```
x = -7
y = -12
```

At least I know this is possible, because I found how to do it by myself. But now I forgot. But I am sure it is possible.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the pair as follows (in this case in a and b).

```
{a, b} = {x, y} /. First@Solve[{2 x + 2 == y, 3 x + 9 == y}, {x, y}]
```

You can relable as you see  fit.

Similarly, you can just substitute in an expression, e.g.

```
x^2 + y^2 /. First@Solve[{2 x + 2 == y, 3 x + 9 == y}, {x, y}]
```

yields 193.

Note in this case there is a unique solution so First is fine.